# Cannot load M3U8: crossdomain access denied

Tags: media, plex

I am getting the error message "Cannot load M3U8: crossdomain access denied" when trying to access my Plex server through the web interface. How do I stop this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This typically happens if you are behind a corperate or school firewall. This is a browser setting that needs changing.

IE: Go to "Internet Options" > "Secuirty" > "Internet" > choose "Custom Level" and scroll down to "Miscellaneous". One of the options should be "Access data sources across domain" - set this to "Enable".

Answer (score 1):

This error can appear when trying to stream video from a website.
In that case the problem could be the "HTTPS Everywhere" browser extension.
Disabling that extension solved the issue for me.